# In R how can I read in a CSV that has additional (faulty) line breaks

Tags: r, csv

My csv file looks something like this:

[image: csvdata]

basically,

first line: ,"id","gender","age","language","frame","householdSize",

second line: 1,1,"male",28,"fr","A

third line: Frame",3

fourth line: 2,2,"nichtbinär",35,"engl","B

fifth line: Frame",5

However, the data has too many line breaks cause "LETTER(s) Frame" should not be broken. However it systematically is. Is there a way to fix this error when reading it into R?

To clarify: I want to keep the start of line 2 and 4 (and many more) - I just want to concatenate all "Something LINEBREAK Frame" because it is a within-observation break.)

[image: datapic]

Comment: Thanks, I guess It won't work cause I still want to have the line break after line 3 and line 5 (as in 2 and 4 and 6 (not shown)  new observations start)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the pattern that the table is 'broken' on, you can fix this:

```r
library(stringr)
library(vroom)
library(dplyr)

input <- readLines("input.csv") # your data here

input
#> [1] "var, frame," "11, A"       "Frame,"      "12, B"       "Frame"

input <- paste(input, collapse = "\n")
input <- paste0(input, "\n") #end on linebreak

input <- str_replace_all(input, "(?<=[:upper:])\\n(?=Frame)", " ")

vroom(input, delim = ",") |> 
  select(-where(\(x) all(is.na(x))))
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...3`
#> Warning: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details,
#> e.g.:
#>   dat <- vroom(...)
#>   problems(dat)
#> Rows: 2 Columns: 3
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (1): frame
#> dbl (1): var
#> lgl (1): ...3
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>     var frame  
#>   <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1    11 A Frame
#> 2    12 B Frame
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. This doesn't work for me - could you maybe add some more comments, please? I struggle to adopt it, cause already input gives me something different: `> input
[1] "\",\"\"id\"\",\"\"gender\"\",\"\"age\"\",\"\"language\"\",\"\"frame\"\",\"\"householdSize\"\",\""
[2] "\"1,1,\"\"male\"\",28,\"\"fr\"\",\"\"A \"" [3] "\"Frame\"\",3\""                                                                                 
[4] "\"2,2,\"\"nichtbin\x8ar\"\",35,\"\"engl\"\",\"\"B\""                                             
[5] "\"Frame\"\",5\""

Comment: Run `dput(input)`, and copy the result into the body of your question, then someone might be able to give you more specific help